ERROR Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AUD')
I am making a currency converter app. My issue is in my function Currency Converter. The AUD that I have as a string in the useState is not being read after i launch the app. I am not sure why as the code was working this morning. But I added a variable and function to convert after someone inputs an amount and that's when I received the error.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

const Base_URL = "https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?from=";

function CurrencyConverter() {
  const [currencyOptions, setCurrencyOptions] = useState([]);
  const [fromCurrency, setFromCurrency] = useState("USD");
  const [toCurrency, setToCurrency] = useState("AUD");
  const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState();
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  const [amountInFromCurrency, setAmountInFromCurrency] = useState(true);

  let toAmount, fromAmount;
  if (amountInFromCurrency) {
    fromAmount = amount;
    toAmount = amount * exchangeRate;
  } else {
    toAmount = amount;
    fromAmount = amount / exchangeRate;
  }

  //console.log(exchangeRate)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(Base_URL + fromCurrency)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCurrencyOptions([data.base, ...Object.keys(data.rates)]);
        setExchangeRate(data.rates);
      });
  }, [fromCurrency]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="text-center p-3 mb-2">
        <h2 className="mb-2">Currency Converter</h2>
      </div>
      <div className="row text-center">
        <Dropdown
          currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
          selectedCurrency={fromCurrency}
          onChangeCurrency={(e) => setFromCurrency(e.target.value)} //<- supposed to take the target event(currency selection) and change it to that option
        />
        <div className="equals">
          {amount}={amount * exchangeRate[toCurrency]}
        </div>
        <Dropdown
          currencyOptions={currencyOptions}
          selectedCurrency={toCurrency}
          onChangeCurrency={(e) => setToCurrency(e.target.value)} //<- supposed to take the target event(currency selection) and change it to that option
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CurrencyConverter;

To solve it I deleted the code I added in and just reverted everything back to the way I had it before but the error is still there.
Here is the code that I think changed everything:
  let toAmount, fromAmount
  if(amountInFromCurrency){
    fromAmount = amount
    toAmount = amount*exchangeRate
  } else{
    toAmount = amount
    fromAmount = amount/exchangeRate
  }

As an extra note this code is from my App.js, please let me know if it would be helpful for me to include my Dropdown.js as well

You're initialising exchangeRate to undefined here... const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState() and trying to read from it here... {amount}={amount * exchangeRate[toCurrency]}. Use conditional rendering or initialise it to something that makes sense
